# Podbird app stops every time

Tags: ubuntu-touch, podcast

Today, the podbird application (from nik90) stops suddenly when downloading an episode of "VOA Learning english" from 11.11.2015. I have a BQ Aquaris phone.

As the app tries to download the episode every time, the app stops every time.

I have to remove the Database files to be able to launch podbird, but my  podcasts configuration is lost.

Do you have another solution ?